# Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message ' * GET Property login does not exist' can any one give me the solution

Tags: php, netbeans

am gettiing this error

Fatal error:

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message ' * GET Property login
>   does not exist' in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\UniversityWork\Project\UniversityProjectPHP\model\Checkout.php:30
>   Stack trace: #0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\UniversityWork\Project\UniversityProjectPHP\views\top.php(44):
>   Checkout->__get('login') #1
>
> E:\xampp\htdocs\UniversityWork\Project\UniversityProjectPHP\checkout.php(9):
>   require_once('E:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\UniversityWork\Project\UniversityProjectPHP\model\Checkout.php
>   on line 30

line 44 look like this

```
if ($obj_user->login && in_array($current, $public_pages)) {

$_SESSION['ref_url'] = $url;
$_SESSION['msg'] = "You must <a href='" . BASE_URL .    "process/process_logout.php'>LOGOUT</a> to view this page";
header("Location:" . BASE_URL . "msg.php");
}
```

line 30 look like

```
public function __get($name) {
    $method_name = "get_$name";

    if (!method_exists($this, $method_name)) {
        **throw new Exception(" * GET Property $name does not exist");**
    }

    return $this->$method_name();
}
```

line number 9 look like this

```
<title> Home shop || Checkout </title>
<?php
require_once 'model/user.php';
require_once 'model/brand.php';
require_once 'model/Checkout.php';
require_once 'model/product.php';
require_once 'model/cart.php';
require_once 'model/category.php';
**require_once 'views/top.php';**
require_once 'model/web_interface.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code:

```
if ($obj_user->login
```

is trying to read the property `login` of the `$obj_user` object, but it does not have the `get_login` property read-accessor.

Much more than that I cannot say from the information you posted.